# Second img in href does not work properly

Tags: html, href

In Chrome version 49.0.2623.87 m and in Firefox 45.0.1, when including two `img` within a `href`, a second `img` tag doesn't respect the "target" option and opens the link in the same window, which is an `iframe`.

```
<a target="_parent" href="oneclickcheckout.asp">
<img border="0" src="images/cart.png" height="35" alt=".." title="..">
<img src="images/checkout.png" height="32" alt="" title="" border="0">
</a>
```

It does the same when I separate the `href`, which is really strange:

```
<a target="_parent" href="oneclickcheckout.asp">
<img border="0" src="images/cart.png" height="35" alt=".." title=".."></a>
<a target="_parent" href="oneclickcheckout.asp">
<img src="images/checkout.png" height="32" alt="" title="" border="0"></a>
```

Comment: Images are self closing, they should end with `/>`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a page containing the frame like this :

```
<iframe src="test.php" name="myframe" id="myframe"></iframe>
```

If you want to make your link work just in your frame, then do this :

```
    <a target="myframe" href="oneclickcheckout.asp">
<img border="0" src="https://www.google.com/images/nav_logo242.png" height="35" alt=".." title="..">
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/nav_logo242.png" height="32" alt="" title="" border="0">
</a>
```

Now if you click on the images, they open the link in your page.  Notice that what i changed was this : The frame has a name and an id. My link's target in the html page that is loaded in the frame is the id of the frame.